# Forced and easy hton/ntoh conversion

Tags: c++, integer, networking, bitwise, portability

## Context:

When sending message across the network, the sender has to convert the message from host byte order to network byte order and the receiver has to do the the reverse -  network order to host order.

There are multiple ways of going about it. One neat way to do is to convert the message to host byte
order as soon as it is received.

Eg:

```
struct Msg {
   uint32_t a;
   uint16_t b;
};

run_ntoh (Msg *m)
{
    m->a = ntohl(m->a);
    m->b = ntohs(m->b);
}

process (Msg *m)
{
   run_ntoh(m);
   further_process(m);   
}
```

But there are cases where this will not work. Say, the message buffer is shared by multiple receivers.
We can always copy the message to local buffer and do it. But that is inefficient if the message is large.

The third option is to always access the fields of 'Msg' using ntohx function. But this is error prone.

a. The user might forget to use ntoh always  - it is not enforced.

b. Also user has to be very careful - use htonl or htons? What if the size of the varible is changed -
    nothing enforces the change of htonl instead of htons if the variable size changes from 16 to 32.

Here my idea is to enforce the use of ntoh, while making it easy for the user.

## Code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

//
// class to extract N number of bytes and form a number
// uint32_t value = ExtractValue<uint32_t>::get(buffer);
//
template <typename T, size_t val = sizeof(T)>
struct ExtractValue {
    static T get (uint8_t *p)
    {
        return (ExtractValue<T, val - 1>::get(p) << 8) |
                static_cast<T>(p[val - 1]);
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct ExtractValue<T, 0> {
    static T get (uint8_t *p)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

// Get a field of the class T, in host byte order.
// The class T is wrapped in NetworkData class. The get() function
// takes the offset to the member as an argument, gets the address
// of field and extract the field
template <typename T>
struct NetworkData {

    using type = T;

    NetworkData (uint8_t *p) : _p(p) {}

    template<typename R, typename U = std::decay_t<R>,
             typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer<U>::value>* =  nullptr>
    U get (uintptr_t offset)
    {
        return ExtractValue<U>::get(_p + offset);
    }

    template<typename R, typename U = std::decay_t<R>,
             typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<U>::value>* = nullptr>
    U get (uintptr_t offset)
    {
        return (U)(_p + offset);
    }

private:
    uint8_t *_p;
};

// Macro to easily call the NetworkData::get()
#define GetNtoh(h, f)  \
    h.get<decltype(decltype(h)::type::f)>(offsetof(decltype(h)::type, f))
```

## Usage:

```
struct Msg {
   uint32_t a;
   uint16_t b;
};

void process (uint8_t *p)
{
    NetworkData<Msg> h(p);

    auto a = GetNtoh(h, a);
    auto b = GetNtoh(h, b);
}
```

It is always better to use something like goolge protobuf to serialize/deserialize. But that is not possible when the sender is legacy code.

Comment: What's the difference of the macros `HTONGET()` and `NTOHGET()`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The difference is in the name.  NetworkToHost and HostToNetwrok are generally mirrors or NOP.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Code Review!  Please review [How do I ask a good Question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Specifically, you will get more insightful reviews if you not only provide your code, but also give an explanation of what it does. The more detail, the better.

Comment: @StephenRauch Well, maybe I didn't understand the (unexplained) context. But I don't actually see the advantage instead of using the `ntohx()`, `htonx()` functions directly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ They were generally macros, whose behavior changed based on endianess of the processor.  Network Order (byte order on the wire) is generally Big Endian.  That says nothing about this particular, undocumented, case, just speaks to the historical naming convention, and two names with the same functionality whose names are an attempt to document the direction of the conversion.

Comment: @Stephen I'm familiar with endianess and usage in network protocols, of course. I still don't get how these should be really used. One or the other based on the target CPU's architecture? Doesn't make sense for me. Also OP shows the implementation of `struct Hton` but the example uses `Ntoh<Msg> h(p);` which isn't given in the code to review. I believe all of that stuff is pretty pointless.

Comment: What are: `hton16` `hton32` `hton64`? I always though it was `htons` and `htonl`?

Comment: @loki There seem to be such definitions in 3rd party libs: https://sourceforge.net/p/cplusplus/libzrtpcpp/ci/cd8e6b0ece3317e599f8ce24c78c0a2ed5a87de9/tree/src/libzrtpcpp/zrtpPacket.h

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Those are some very limited conversions. What happens if me code is running on PDP-11? Also all the interesting code is rmoved with `#if 0`

Comment: @Stephen I have added the context for the code.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ  I have added the context of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Unqualified names from C headers

It appears that your `<cstdint>` happens to declare its identifiers in the global namespace as well as in `std`; this means that you weren't notified of the consistent misspelling of `std::uint8_t`, `std::uint16_t` and the like.

## Interface

It's not clear why `ExtractValue` is visible at file scope (rather than being a private static method within `NetworkData`).

The `get()` methods ought to be declared `const` (and if you never implement `set()` methods, then perhaps `_p` should be a pointer-to-const).

## Pass pointer to member rather than `offsetof`

The use of `offsetof()` and pointer arithmetic with `std::uint8_t*` (which should be `char*`, given that `offsetof()` works in units of `char`) is deeply disturbing.  One possibility is for `NetworkData<T>` to hold a private *reference* to the `T`, and accept pointer-to-member to indicate which value is desired:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

// Get a field of the class T, in host byte order.
// The class T is wrapped in NetworkData class. The get() function
// takes the offset to the member as an argument, gets the address
// of field and extract the field
template <typename T>
class NetworkData
{
    const T& data;

public:
    NetworkData (void *data)
        : data(*reinterpret_cast<T*>(data))
    {
    }

    template<typename V>
    V get(V T::*field) const
    {
#if BIG_ENDIAN
        return data.*field;
#else
        return byte_swap(data.*field);
#endif
    }

private:
    template<typename V>
    static
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<V> && std::is_signed_v<V>, V>
    byte_swap(V value)
    {
        // We manipulate using unsigned bitwise arithmetic.
        return reinterpret_cast<V>(byte_swap(reinterpret_cast<std::make_unsigned_t<V>>(value)));
    }

    template<typename V>
    static
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<V> && std::is_unsigned_v<V>, V>
    byte_swap(V value)
    {
        // We assume CHAR_BIT == 8 (so that sizeof gives us octets)
        static const V mask = 0xff;
        V result = 0;
        for (auto shift = 0u;  shift < 8 * sizeof value;  shift += 8)
            result = (result << 8) + ((value >> shift) & mask);
        return result;
    }

    // We could add overloads here to take advantage of processor-native byte swap instructions, as available.
};
```

We can then use it like this:

```
#include <cstdint>
struct Msg {
   std::uint32_t a;
   std::uint16_t b;
};

void process (std::uint8_t *p)
{
    NetworkData<Msg> h(p);

    auto a = h.get(&Msg::a);
    auto b = h.get(&Msg::b);
}
```

This eliminates the use of preprocessor macros, and makes a slightly more natural object-access syntax.

## Consider modifying the structure members

If we're allowed to re-write `Msg`, we could make its members be network-endian values:

```
#include <cstdint>
struct Msg {
   NetworkEndian<std::uint32_t> a;
   NetworkEndian<std::uint16_t> b;
};
```

We can declare NetworkEndian like this:

```
template<typename Integer>
class NetworkEndian
{
    Integer value;

public:
    NetworkEndian(Integer value)
        : value(byte_swap(value))
    {}
    // default copy, assign, destructor

    operator Integer() const
    {
        return byte_swap(value);
    }

private:
    static Integer byte_swap(Integer v)
    {
        using Unsigned = std::make_unsigned_t<Integer>;
        Unsigned u = reinterpret_cast<Unsigned>(v);
        // Assume CHAR_BIT == 8 (so that sizeof gives us octets)
        static const Unsigned mask = 0xff;
        Unsigned result = 0;
        for (auto shift = 0u;  shift < 8 * sizeof u;  shift += 8)
            result = (result << 8) + ((u >> shift) & mask);
        return reinterpret_cast<Integer>(result);
    }
};
```

The conversion operators mean that we can now read the members in a completely natural manner:

```
void process(const Msg& message)
{
    auto a = message.a;
    auto b = message.b;
}
```

Not only that, but by providing a converting constructor, we also get to *assign* values equally naturally.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Couple of things 1: NetworkData (void *data) : data(*reinterpret_cast<T*>(data))' - there is no alignment guarantee of 'void * data'. So type casting it to T * is not strictly valid. But I haven't mentioned that in the original question.  But that's the reason for  the gimmick with the offsetof - which I think is okay given we are dealing with POD types. Also we want avoid memcpy to a aligned location. If we can do the memcpy, the need for this interface goes away, as we can deserilize it such that all fields are converted in one shot.

Comment: Second thing changing the Msg structure is not possible - it is shared with legacy C code. But the code you shared will be useful in other context. Also thanks for the comments one std::uint.. , get should be const - yes. Extract value is in file scope as it is a generic class to extract an integral type T from a unaligned buffer.

Comment: Yes, I did think that the definition of `Msg` might be externally-imposed; that's why I put that section at the end, and prefaced it with "if" - I hope that gives some insight, anyway.  And you're right that I hadn't considered alignment - I admit that I had assumed that the caller had arranged that.  (P.S. if you found my answer helpful, you may *vote* using the `^` button; wait a while for any other answers before choosing one to *accept*).